# Pass parameter to gradle task

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I have multiple tasks. I run a task from command line via : `gradle tasks.gradle TaskA -Pparam1=value1 -Pparam2=value2`

TaskA calls TaskB via : `tasks.TaskB.execute()`.

How can I pass parameters to this task programatically?

Comment: In general you should avoid tasks directly executing each other - tasks are not functions.  The intent of Gradle is to allow you to construct a task graph via dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

As in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47307695/pass-parameter-to-gradle-task#comment81565607_47307695) comment, please **do not** call execute on task directly. Not only it may spoil the task dependency graph but this is also not the case that task action is always mapped to `execute` method.

To read the properties in the task, use:

```
project.findProperty("<PROPERTY_NAME>")
```

It returns `null` if property is missing or value if it was passed.